# XCode 4 - how to build a "lite" version

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

In xcode3 this was easily accomplished by creating a new target and then setting compiler flags to #ifdef LITE_VERSION.

But how do you do this in XCode 4? The compiler flags have moved to the project so if I set -DLITE_VERSION it will affect both my targets...

Have you found a way around this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new scheme, you can find it in the menu "Product" => "New scheme..."

Comment: I actually found that you can still do the same thing in xcode4. Duplicate target > Build settings > All. Just a bit hidden but it's there.