# How to differentiate multiple targets with Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2, target, build-settings

I've developed a lite version of an app. Now I want to create a paid version. 
So I've duplicated the target, changed its name (so change plist and other stuff with that name) and now I have to differentiate in code. I'm using Xcode 4.2 and I see on the web that I have to create a preprocessor flag. My problem is that this flag in Xcode 4.2 is only in the  project's build setting and not in the target's build setting.

I will need to be able to do something like this:

```
#ifdef paid
    ...
#else
    ...
#endif
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode 4 - how to build a "lite" version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605146/xcode-4-how-to-build-a-lite-version)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use preprocessor macros to do this.
Go to Target -> Build Setting and choose "All configurations" (this is very important).
Next find field "Preprocessor Macros".

In this field, add the flag in ex. PAID_VERSION. Now you can use this flag in code:

```
#ifdef PAID_VERSION
    NSLog(@"Paid version");
#else
    NSLog(@"Lite version");
#endif
```

Comment: i didn't find preprocessor for target cause i didn't choose all configuration :) THANKS!