# How derive projects from a single project Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have four different projects which deffer only in a header file and icon files.For making a simple change I have to do it in all the projects. 
Is there any way to combine these projects? But I want 4 different applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make multiple taget.

Click on your project name in the navigator.
In the targets section, duplicate your current target. 
Now you can make change in this target, like change icon, package name.

For the header file, you can use [preprocessor macros to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848263/how-to-differentiate-multiple-targets-with-xcode-4-2?answertab=active#tab-top)

I'm using this to make 5 versions of an application, which differ only with a .h file.